# Why is Android SearchView not showing suggestions?

Tags: android, adapter, searchview

Code in Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_items, menu);
    initSearchViewWidget(menu);
    setSearchViewOnQueryTextListener();
    setSearchViewOnSuggestionListener();
    setSearchViewOnCloseListener();
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void initSearchViewWidget(Menu menu){
    MenuItem menuItemSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.globalSearchView);
    searchView = (SearchView) menuItemSearch.getActionView();
}

private void setSearchViewOnQueryTextListener(){
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            startUsersSearchInMainFragment(query, false);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            startUsersSearchInMainFragment(newText, true);
            filterFriendsListInCabinetFragment(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void setSearchViewOnSuggestionListener(){
    searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
            CursorAdapter adapter = searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter();
            Cursor cursor = adapter.getCursor();
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                if(cursor.getPosition() == position){
                    String value = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(UsersSearchAutocomplete.COLUMN_ALT));
                    searchView.setQuery(value, true);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                }else{
                    if(cursor.move(position)){
                        String value = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(UsersSearchAutocomplete.COLUMN_ALT));
                        searchView.setQuery(value, true);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                    }
                }

            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
            CursorAdapter adapter = searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter();
            Cursor cursor = adapter.getCursor();
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                if(cursor.getPosition() == position){
                    String value = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(UsersSearchAutocomplete.COLUMN_ALT));
                    searchView.setQuery(value, true);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                }else{
                    if(cursor.move(position)){
                        String value = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(UsersSearchAutocomplete.COLUMN_ALT));
                        searchView.setQuery(value, true);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                    }
                }

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void setSearchViewOnCloseListener(){
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            reloadMainFragment();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void startUsersSearchInMainFragment(String query, boolean autocomplete) {
    if (fragment instanceof MainFragment) {
        ((MainFragment) fragment).cancelAsyncTasks();
        ((MainFragment) fragment).setFragmentDataWithQuery(query);
        if (autocomplete) {
            if (query.length() > 1) {
                cancelAutocompleteAsyncTask();
                usersSearchAutocomplete = new UsersSearchAutocomplete(MainActivity.this, query);
                usersSearchAutocomplete.execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code in AsyncTask

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] suggests) {
    super.onPostExecute(suggests);
    if(suggests != null){
        if(suggests.length > 0){
            String[] columnNames = {COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_ALT};
            final MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(columnNames);
            for(int id = 0; id < suggests.length; id++){
                String[] temp = new String[2];
                temp[0] = String.valueOf(id);
                temp[1] = suggests[id];
                cursor.addRow(temp);
            }
            try{
                Dialogs.createShortToast(activity.getApplicationContext(), Arrays.toString(suggests));
                ((MainActivity) activity).suggestCursor = null;
                ((MainActivity)activity).suggestCursor = cursor;
                ((MainActivity)activity).autocompleteAdapter = null;
                ((MainActivity)activity).autocompleteAdapter = new UsersSearchAutocompleteAdapter(activity.getApplicationContext(), ((MainActivity)activity).suggestCursor, 0);
                ((MainActivity)activity).getSearchView().setSuggestionsAdapter(null);
                ((MainActivity)activity).getSearchView().setSuggestionsAdapter(((MainActivity)activity).autocompleteAdapter);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My adapter

```
public class UsersSearchAutocompleteAdapter extends CursorAdapter {


public UsersSearchAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.search_autocomplete_item, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.searchAutocompleteTextView);
    String alt = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("alt"));
    textView.setText(alt);
}
```

}

I use android.support.v7.widget.SearchView. Suggests search started when typing text's length will > of 1 symbols. But suggestions shows under searchview not every tyme when I typing text.